# How to expand this expression in series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, math-history

From Poisson's first *Memoire sur la distribution d'electricite* (1812), $\S$39. Suppose $b$ is very small relative to $c-a$ where $a,b,c$ are positive real scalars. Consider the equations
\begin{align*}
af(x)+\frac{b^2}{c-ax} F\left(\frac{b}{c-ax}\right)&=h,\\
bF(x)+\frac{a^2}{c-bx}f\left(\frac{a}{c-bx}\right)&=g;
\end{align*}
for arbitrary functions $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ (representing the "number of electric molecules" on a surface in the original memoir), for $x\in[-1,1]$. The variables $g$ and $h$ are arbitrary constants. With the assumption that $b$ is very smaller relative to $c-a$, we may neglect the cubes of $\frac{b}{c}$.

Given the above, Poisson says that the expansion of $bF(x)$ (presumably about $x=\frac{a}{c}$) takes the form:
\begin{align*}
bF&(x)=g-\frac{a^2}{c}f\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)-\left[\frac{a^2}{c}f\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)+\frac{a^3}{c^2}f'\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)\right]\frac{bx}{c}\\
&-\left[\frac{a^2}{c}f\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)+\frac{2a^3}{c^2} f'\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)+\frac{a^4}{2c^3}f''\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)\right]\frac{b^2x}{c^2};
\end{align*}

Some notes before I go on: Poisson used the notation $fx$ for function $f$, which I have assumed is intended to represent the form $f(x)$. There may be other results related to the above series expansion earlier (some time after $\S$15) but I haven't found anything.

Now, the presence of derivatives brings Taylor series to mind, but expanding about $x=\frac{c}{a}$ gives
$$ bF(x) \approx g-\frac{a^2}{c-bx}\left[ f\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)+f'\left(\frac{c}{a}\right) \left(x-\frac{c}{a}\right)+\frac{1}{2} f''\left(\frac{c}{a}\right) \left(x-\frac{c}{a}\right)^2 \right] $$
Which is far different.

**Question**: How do you go from the above equations to the expansion for $bF(x)$ given?

For context, I'm writing a translation of the memoir (which [is available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m9jLvjLyXQDBEwEoDhrco3UJIF-fi7fJ/view?usp=sharing)). The closest to useful result I've found is this equation:
$$
af\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-\frac{a^2b}{c^2-b^2-cx}f\left(\frac{ac-ax}{c^2-b^2-cx}\right)=h-\frac{gb}{c-x}\quad (3)
$$
An equation which Poisson says must be integrated, in general, to solve for $f(x)$, which can then be used to solve $F(x)$. But it's not clear still what is happening above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion is around $x=0$.
Then $$bF(x)=g-\frac{a^2}{c-bx}f\left(\frac a{c-bx}\right)$$
Expanding in Taylor series at $x=0$, the constant term is $$g-\frac{a^2}cf\left(\frac ac\right)$$
The linear term is given by the first derivative:
$$\left(g-\frac{a^2}{c-bx}f\left(\frac a{c-bx}\right)\right)'=\frac{a^2}{(c-bx)^2}(-b)f\left(\frac a{c-bx}\right)-\frac{a^2}{c-bx}f'\left(\frac a{c-bx}\right)\left(\frac a{c-bx}\right)'\\=-\frac{a^2b}{(c-bx)^2}f\left(\frac a{c-bx}\right)-\frac{a^3b}{(c-bx)^3}f'\left(\frac a{c-bx}\right)$$
Taking the value at $x=0$ you get $$\left(g-\frac{a^2}{c-bx}f\left(\frac a{c-bx}\right)\right)'_{x=0}=-\frac{a^2b}{c^2}f\left(\frac a{c}\right)-\frac{a^3b}{c^3}f'\left(\frac a{c}\right)$$
You can do the same for the next derivative. Up to the first order, $$bF(x)=g-\frac{a^2}cf\left(\frac ac\right)-\left[\frac{a^2b}{c^2}f\left(\frac a{c}\right)+\frac{a^3b}{c^3}f'\left(\frac a{c}\right)\right]x\\=g-\frac{a^2}cf\left(\frac ac\right)-\left[\frac{a^2}{c}f\left(\frac a{c}\right)+\frac{a^3}{c^2}f'\left(\frac a{c}\right)\right]\frac{bx}c$$